# Create library in Borland 4.5

Tags: c++, c, borland-c++

I am trying to compile very old Borland C code using Borland4.5 and 3.1 on  Windows7 32bit.

Able to compile but, when I say create Library it is giving error on both 4.5 and 3.1.

Library Page size is 32 and tried to increase till 128. Still same error.

```
Building C:\PROGS\LIB\tlw.lib:

Librarian Error: renaming 'C:\PROGS\LIB\TLIBTEMP.000' to 'C:\PROGS\LIB\tlw.lib'
```

I renamed manually TLIBTEMP.000 to tlw.lib, but it is not recognised.

Thanks,

Comment: I doubt you'll find help with a twenty-old compiler, if even Borland no longer supports it.

Comment: Support for Windows 7 ended on January 14, 2020.  Borland C++ 4.5 was released in 1995 for Windows 3.1.  I think this endeavor may be a bit Don Quixote-esque.